# Let a picture on drop is the div is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code, I'm new to coding and I'm doing a project. I have a few divs and I want to have some objects that drag into the space only is the div is empty. It would be very helpful if you anyone can help me thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {   
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
</style>
    <script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()
    }

    function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()

    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
}

function test_div_child() {
    //var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
    //alert(x[0].innerHTML);
    var x = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML
    //alert(x.length)

    if(x.length<=5){
        alert("then drop image");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>first</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>then</p>
        <td>
            <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>
    <tr>
<table>
<div>
<p>Image Gallery</p>
<img src="testphoto.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2"> 
<img src="testphoto.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3"> 
<img src="testphoto.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4"> 
<img src="testphoto.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag5"> 
<img src="testphoto.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag6">
</div>
<div><button type="button" onclick="test_div_child()">Test Div Child</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (div == 'element')
{

}
```

add this into the function that control is you can drop an element or not. It looks to see if a div contains an element.

In an example code, you can have it this way:

```
function drop(ev, div) {
ev.preventDefault()
if(div == 'div4') 
{
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
    var element = document.getElementById(data)
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
}
else if (div == 'element')
{

}
else
{
    if(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML <= 5)
    {
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
    }
}}

<p id="element"><img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/illustrations/cute-bright-red-apple-icon-isolated-on-white-illustration-id90692172?k=6&m=90692172&s=170667a&w=0&h=QxpaX5OjVcoN5VPxptnOM_sWuCOB2VNDAdQEJ_Qx5zU=" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="100" height="100"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should format your divs like:

```
<div id="tags"><font size="7">&nbspAfter&nbsp&nbsp</font></div>&nbsp<br><br><br><br>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>
```

with:

```
function allowDrop(ev, div) {
ev.preventDefault()
```

}